# How to set TextField's placeholder text to fit into the field

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a textfield for searching phrases. This textfield has a placeholder with a little bit longer text (in Japanese). It is fine at iPhone 11, but it shortened at SE with `...`. I would like to know how set autoscaling with factor like 0.6 for this text.

[image: textfield]

Comment: you should have to use attributed text for placeholder

Answer (score -1):

Use placeholder programmatically:

```
    let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: yourText,
                                                    attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray])
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6
    label.attributedText = attributedPlaceholder
```